# select distinct sum of item that can exists in several tables

Tags: sqlite

Let's say that i have 3 tables: Articles1,Articles2,Articles3.

It's possible that same articlegroup exists in two of theese tables.
I only want to sum amount by each articlegroup existing in Articles1 and does not exists in the other tables.

**Tables:**

Articles1

```
| Id    |    ArticleName    |    Amount |
-----------------------------------------
  '1'         'Apple'              '2'
  '2'         'Orange'             '2'
  '3'         'Banana'             '3'
```

Articles2

```
| Id    |    ArticleName    |    Amount |
-----------------------------------------
  '1'         'Apple'              '2'
  '2'         'Orange'             '2'
```

Articles3

```
| Id    |    ArticleName    |    Amount |
-----------------------------------------
  '1'         'Apple'              '2'
  '2'         'Orange'             '2'
```

**My code:**

```
SELECT SUM(a1.Amount) 
FROM Articles1 a1
LEFT OUTER JOIN Articles2 a2
   ON a1.Id = a2.Id
LEFT OUTER JOIN Articles3 a3
   ON a1.Id = a3.Id
WHERE a1.Id <> a2.Id OR a1.Id <> a3.Id
GROUP BY a1.ArticleName
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/929c7/2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modified your query to

```
select sum(a1.Amount)
FROM Articles1 a1
WHERE 
a1.Id not in (select Id from Articles2) and 
a1.Id not in (select Id from Articles3)
GROUP BY a1.ArticleName
```

This returns 3 as output i.e. only for Banana.

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/26bc7/2)